# MySQL: max count and column name

Tags: mysql

I have `student`, `course` and `student_has_course` tables.

in student (`id`, `name` ...)
in course (`id`, `name` ...)
in student_has_course (`student_id`, `course_id`)

I want to get "most populated course" count and name.

With this I can get max populated course count but I can't figure out how I can get course name aswell.

```
SELECT MAX(counted)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted
    FROM student_has_course
    GROUP BY course_ID
) AS counts;
```

Comment: try inner join to get result

Comment: @RohitKumar could you please give me the right syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT COUNT(shc.course_id) as cnt, c.name
FROM student_has_course shc 
JOIN course c ON (c.course_id = shc.course_id)
GROUP BY shc.course_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.name, sc.cnt
FROM
    course c
    INNER JOIN (SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM student_has_course GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1) cs ON c.id=cs.course_id
```

Comment: Just to ensure right ordering I would add another order by. Most likely it will not be used but to ensure correct sorting of output as it's not 100% clear how to optimizer is doing the join in the end.

Comment: @frlan, since the sub-query returns only one row, i suppose this wont be an issue